# multiselect treeview in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and trying to establish some good paradigms.

Right now, I'm working on a search heavy site. There are dozens of attributes to search on, many are min max type, but 6 or so are multi select. Prior to backbone, I was using something called listtree to make a collapsible listtree for the multiselect options. I'm still going to use those css classes, but now I'm trying to use backbone with models and views. TBH, this seems like more work than just using straight jquery, so maybe I'm missing something.

My question is, how should I structure the models and the views for several multiselect widgets in a treeview?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<script type='text/template' id='listtree_bs'>
<div class="listtree">
    <ul>
        <% _.each(context, function(element, index){ %>
        <li>
            <span>
                <input class="checkbox-listview-master" type="checkbox" value="<%= element.value %>"><%= element.name %><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
            </span>
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <% _.each(element.items, function(childelement, index){ %>
                <li>
                    <span>
                        <input class="checkbox-listview-master" type="checkbox" value="<%= childelement.value %>"><%= childelement.name %><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
                    </span>
                </li>
                <% }); %>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>
</div>
</script>



var ListTreeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/search/multiselect/",
    idAttribute:'value',
});

var ListTreeModels = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ListTreeModel,
    url: "/search/multiselect/",
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.data;
    }
});

var listtreemodels = new ListTreeModels();
listtreemodels.fetch()

var ListTreeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "treechecked": "treechecked"
    },
    treechecked: function( e ){
         console.log('triggered');

});

var listtreeview = new ListTreeView({el: $('#listtree_bs')});
```

The response.data from above looks kind of like this (I can easily change the backend though to facilitate the front end)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "other": 0,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 1,
          "key": "type (35513)"
        }
      ],
      "value": "type_of_code",
      "key": "C Type",
      "missing": 275793
    },
    {
      "other": 25273,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 41,
          "key": "United States of America (187293)"
        }
      ],
      "value": "primary_country_id",
      "key": "Primary Country",
      "missing": 3475
    },
    {
      "other": 10958,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 623,
          "key": "company 623 (12602)"
        }
      ],
      "value": "controller_id",
      "key": "Search by Controller",
      "missing": 248288
    },
    {
      "other": 1294,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 6,
          "key": "animal type (247267)"
        },
        {
          "value": 7,
          "key": "animal type y (23315)"
        }
      ],
      "value": "animal_id",
      "key": "Animals",
      "missing": 0
    },
    {
      "other": 0,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 5,
          "key": "Inactive (63693)"
        },
        {
          "value": 1,
          "key": "Active (825)"
        }
      ],
      "value": "current_status_code_table_id",
      "key": "Current Status",
      "missing": 109101
    },
    {
      "other": 0,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 0,
          "key": "stuff (275058)"
        },
        {
          "value": 1,
          "key": "more stuff (39860)"
        },
        {
          "value": 2,
          "key": "even more stuff (668)"
        }
      ],
      "value": "stuff_indicator",
      "key": "Stuff Indicator",
      "missing": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

so right now, models are populated at the data level, but should they be populated at the nested level and manage this with some kind of one to many relationship?

What these multiselects do is fill out a search form that will get sent back to the server when the user hits search. Can I bind the above views to the model even if they are nested?

I'm trying backbone as an experiment here, but is this what it was really designed for? The search results are complicated and are sliced down in dozens of views. I was hoping to use backbone to keep the dom light and nimble. Right now it's getting bogged down in a lot of event call backs and just a lot of html.

Comment: I think, better ask this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a hierarchy of models is not that difficult : you just have to build your submodels when you parse the data. One way to do it is

```
var ListTreeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/search/multiselect/",
    idAttribute:'value',

    constructor: function(data, opts) {
        // force the parsing of the data
        opts = _.extend({}, opts, {parse: true});

        // setup the children collection
        this.values = new ListTreeModels();

        // call the parent constructor
        Backbone.Model.call(this, data, opts);
    },
    parse: function(data) {
        // populate the children
        if (_.isArray(data.values))
            this.values.set(data.values);

        // remove the children from th emodel attributes
        return _.omit(data, 'values');
    }
});

var ListTreeModels = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ListTreeModel,
    url: "/search/multiselect/",
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.data;
    }
});
```

A demo showing the result http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/pZU5J/

Once your model structure is up and running, you can render your views (generate the associated HTML) and defined events. Here is a sample way to do it:

```
var ListTreeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    'tagName': 'ul',
    render: function () {
        var $el = this.$el;
        //create a view for each model
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            var view = new ListItemView({
                model: model
            });
            $el.append(view.render().el);
        });        
        return this;
    }
});
var ListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    'tagName': 'li',
    events: {
        'click ': function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation(); // avoid triggering an event on the parent level
            console.log(this.model.get('value'));
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        //render the node
        var template = _.template($('#listitem').html());
        this.$el.html(template(this.model.toJSON()));

        //and add a view for the sub collection            
        var subview = new ListTreeView({
            collection: this.model.values
        });
        this.$el.append(subview.render().el);
        return this;
    }
});
```

with the `listitem` template defined as

```
<script type='text/template' id='listitem'>
<span>
    <input class="checkbox-listview" type="checkbox" value="<%= value %>"> <%= key %>
</span>
</script>
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/pZU5J/3/

Hierarchical views can be tricky to render, you probably will have to investigate further on the matter.